# nlua Adding a Lua script to a button, all from the Lua language

Tags: c#

I'm writing code that will open a menu with an input field and a button, I didn't find a way to add an action to the button, I get an error

```
import('System')
import('System.IO')
import('System.Windows.Forms')
import('System.Drawing')

local form = Form()
form.Text = "Rename your filename"
form.Size = Size(300, 200)
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

local textBox = TextBox()
textBox.Location = Point(10, 10)
textBox.Size = Size(260, 20)

local button = Button()
button.Text = "Submit"
button.Location = Point(10, 40)

local function onButtonClick(sender, eventArgs)
  MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели: " .. textBox.Text)
end

button.Click:Add(onButtonClick)

form.Controls:Add(textBox)
form.Controls:Add(button)

Application.Run(form)
```

Phew, I tried to run the Lua function using the C# library from the Lua language, it turned out that it doesn't work that way, and in general went into some kind of thicket, maybe someone has met with something like this, how can I solve it?